# Spring batch step read_count, write_count and commit_count keep on increasing without any rollbacks or skips

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am investigating a spring batch job developed by someone else.
Each step reads from the database in its reader, transforms the read JPA entities to DTOs in processor and the writer does several operations on each of these DTOs that may involve database queries, third party API calls, or both.

The JPQL used in the reader picks only 105 records (`limit 105` is attached to the resulting SQL query) - I am using `org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader` and passing `pageSize=105`. Also, I have overridden `org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader#getPage` to always return 0. This is because the table continuously gets new entries inserted; keeping `getPage` to its default implementation could risk missing some records. The JPQL used in reader itself takes care of the ordering and filtering of relevant records.

Each step is configured to operate on the read records in chunks of 15 records.
However, the read_count, write_count are much higher considering the record limit and chunk size configurations:

```
postgres_database=> select * from batch_step_execution where step_execution_id = 445124;
step_execution_id | version |              step_name              | job_execution_id |       start_time        |        end_time         |  status   | commit_count | read_count | filter_count | write_count | read_skip_count | write_skip_count |
 process_skip_count | rollback_count | exit_code | exit_message |      last_updated
-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
--------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------
            445124 |     896 | step1 |           278076 | 2023-01-27 16:08:02.074 | 2023-01-29 21:41:09.375 | COMPLETED |          894 |      13395 |            0 |       13395 |               0 |                0 |
                  0 |              0 | COMPLETED |              | 2023-01-29 21:41:09.375
(1 row)
```

As can be seen, the read_count is 13395 (while a limit of 105 gets attached to the reader JPQL as mentioned earlier), write_count = read_count. I was thinking in terms of possible retries, but based on what I found about Spring Batch, the rollback_count should be >0 (since a retry is preceded by a rollback).

Adding the step configuration for reference:

```
  @Bean
  public Step step1(
      StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
      ItemReader<JPAEntity> reader,
      ItemWriter<DTO> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("step1")
        .<JPAEntity, DTO>chunk(15)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor((ItemProcessor<JPAEntity, DTO>) Transformer::fromEntityToDto)
        .writer(writer)
        .faultTolerant()
        .noRollback(Exception.class)
        .build();
  }
```

I have been unable to figure out why this could be happening.
I found Spring Batch docs weren't that helpful, and couldn't see anything similar being discussed in any other thread (on StackOverflow, or anywhere else).

Any kind of help would be highly appreaciated.
Thank you.

I went through Spring Batch docs, read a few articles, stackoverflow answers. But found nothing. Even ran a simple Spring Batch job but never saw it happen in that application.

Comment: That should not be the case. The only situation that can cause such issues is when the step is multi-threaded. But the step you shared is not multi-threaded, so I don't really see how this could happen. If you share a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, I can try to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The rollback count is zero because of `.norollback(Exception.class)`. It is not going to rollback all exception. All exception in java extends Exception class. More details on doc below.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#noRollback(java.lang.Class)

Comment: Yes, but noRollback applies only to read and process phases of a step.
Nonetheless, if it's not rolling anything back how come the read_count and write_count more than the limit of 105? If noRollback were working, then it would have simply done nothing for any exception and read_count/write_count shouldn't have been more than 105.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarMahto JPQL does not support limit clause. You want to use `setMaxItemCount` method in your item reader (JpaCursorItemReader) to limit records.

Comment: I conveyed it wrong - limit clause gets attached to the resultant SQL query - made this correction to the question as well. I am using org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader and passing 105 as the pageSize to it. I used IDE debugger to get the SQL query that's finally executed which contains the limit 105 clause. Also I have overridden getPage to always return 0. Please read the second paragraph - I have added more context. Thank you for pointing that out.